# Catel's AsynchronousCommand correct usage

Tags: catel

I've to call an async Task using a command. I tought that AsynchronousCommand would have done the trick but it accepts an Action as method so I've to use something as

```
public async void Something(object args)
```

would it be supposed to accept a Task on Command's definition?

## UPDATE #1

Used TaskCommand as suggested by @Geert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Async void is very bad, because it cannot be awaited (meaning you can cause a lot of issues). Either use `async Task ExecuteAsync` or `void Execute`.